# How to trim/strip leading whitespaces from StringField for list view in Django/Mongodb?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

Want to sort data by names, but unfortunately there are many data with leading whitespaces, that is why `rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter` doesn't work properly. Mongo, DRF are used in my project.

My model:

```py
from mongoengine import DynamicDocument, fields

class Book(DynamicDocument):
    name = fields.StringField(required=True)
    description = fields.StringField(blank=True, null=True)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'books',
        'strict': False,
    }
```

My view:

```py
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
from rest_framework_mongoengine import viewsets

from core.serializers import BookSerializer
from core.models import Book

class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['name']
    ordering = ['name']
```

Someone has any idea, how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is aggregation operation called [$trim](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/) in mongoDB that you can use to sanitize the string data  , if you want to remove only the leading spaces then you can use the [$ltrim](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ltrim/#mongodb-expression-exp.-ltrim) ...

Answer (score 0):

If someone deals with `mongoengine`, you can solve this problem with `queryset.aggregate()`:

```py
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        pipeline = [
            {
                '$project': {
                    'id': {'$toString': '$_id'},
                    'name': 1,
                    'ltrim_lower_name': {'$ltrim': {'input': {'$toLower': '$name'}}},
                    'description': 1,
                }
            },
            {'$sort': {'ltrim_lower_name': 1}}
        ]

        return queryset.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Used `python 'trim_lower_name': {'$ltrim': {'input': {'$toLower': '$name'}}}` because need case-insensitive sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Also find one more decision for this question

utils.py:

```py
collation = dict(
    locale='en',
    caseLevel=False,
    caseFirst='off',
    strength=1,
    numericOrdering=True,
    alternate='shifted',
    maxVariable='space',
    backwards=False,
)
```

In views.py:

```py
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        return queryset.collation(collation)
```